# wireless tethering problem on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, internet-connection, tethering

I'm trying to access the internet on my laptop using wireless tethering option on my android phone. I'm able to make DNS queries and also ping my Gateway but i'm neither able to ping other sites like www.google.com nor access internet. Here is the output of some commands that might help in resolving the issue,

```
itachi@itachi-laptop:~$ uname -a

Linux itachi-laptop 3.2.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 10:49:02 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux


itachi@itachi-laptop:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"


itachi@itachi-laptop:~$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0



itachi@itachi-laptop:~$ ping 192.168.43.1

PING 192.168.43.1 (192.168.43.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from 192.168.43.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1.96 ms

64 bytes from 192.168.43.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=1.99 ms

64 bytes from 192.168.43.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=2.00 ms
^C
--- 192.168.43.1 ping statistics ---



itachi@itachi-laptop:~$ ping www.google.com

PING www.google.com (74.125.236.84) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---

40 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 39313ms



itachi@itachi-laptop:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection [8086:4229] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1120]
    Kernel driver in use: iwl4965


itachi@itachi-laptop:~$ ifconfig wlan0

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:5c:6a:3d:11  
          inet addr:192.168.43.224  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:5cff:fe6a:3d11/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3994 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:64469 (64.4 KB)  TX bytes:427656 (427.6 KB)
```

I'm able to access the internet when I directly connect via a usb-dongle and that is why i'm posting this question. When I try using wifi tethering though, I'm unable to ping nor access internet. Any help to resolve this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android are you using?

Being able to ping your gateway just says it can talk to your phone - which implies the issue is with the phone's forwarding of packets. The reference to www.google.com may be a cached DNS entry, not live. I'm currently trying something similar with bluetooth, and seeing reports of JellyBean's tethering being crippled.

Answer (score 0):

look if this file exists

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

or

```
/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

if one is missing. Do this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

For the first question answer: `yes`

For the second question answer: `no` (no = do not append old configuration)

reboot